# bind directive action to parent controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, isolate-scope

I have a directive for profile update and I want to trigger update action from the parent scope.
Here what look like my code:

> main.js

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('profile',{
    scope: {
        updateFromDirective: "="
    },
    template: '<form><input ng-model="name"/></form>',
    controller: function(){
        this.updateFromDirective = function(){
            /* update here */
        };
    }
})
.controller('Ctrl', function(){
    this.updateFromController = function(){
        if(condition){
            /* how do I call updateFromDirective here ??? */
        }
    };
});
```

> index.html

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <profile updateFromDirective="updateFromController"></profile>
    <button ng-click="updateFromController()">Update</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly you have to do here ? and what is the error ?

Comment: when click on update trigger updateFromController then call updateFromDirective, it work when passing updateFromDirective to rootScope

Comment: share plunker example so i ll see where the error is gettting.

Comment: please reframe your question, its a bit tricky to get understood, you have a button and an action in parent controller, what is the need of a function in your directive,,what is its use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your function reference to the directive using `'&'` if you are passing like this `updateFromController()` else use `'='` for `updateFromController` (both will work)

**Now in your case**

***Note:*** I'm assuming that you don't want to use $scope since you have your functions in controllers with this

To call a controller function from the directive you need to pass it as callback and can call that callback like below

```
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('Ctrl', function(){
    this.updateFromController = function(){
         alert('In Contrller')
    };
}).directive('profile',function(){
   return{
    scope:{
      controllercallback: "&"
    },
    template:'<input ng-model="name"/><br/><button ng-click="ctrl.updateFromDirective()">Update</button>',
    controller:function(){
      this.updateFromDirective=function(){
        alert('In Directive')
        this.controllercallback();
      }
    },
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs:'ctrl'
  }

})
```

Your html should look like below

```
 <div ng-controller="Ctrl as vm">
 <profile controllercallback="vm.updateFromController()"></profile>
```

But here your button is in the directive itself.

If you don't want your button to be part of your directive you can use publish/subscriber model given by angular like below

```
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
    this.updateFromController = function(){
         $scope.broadcast('calldirective');
    };
}).directive('profile',function(){
   return{
    template:'<input ng-model="name"/>',
    controller:function($scope){
       $scope.$on('calldirective', function() {
         alert('In Directive')
       }); 

    }



}

})
```

Comment: how do I call updateFromDirective within updateFromController ?

Comment: Thanks @Rishi, but the problem is that the button is not on directive's template